# Flutter: get all user inputs from a subtree?

Tags: flutter, navigation, widget

Flutter: how to get parent and all child widgets of a widget (not test code)?

Widget tree:

```
    Subtree_root
      WidgetA
        ChildA
           TextField
        ChildB
           GrandChildC
             TextField
             DropdownMenu
```

Trying to navigate a subtree recursively and find all user inputs, collect them and send them as Http request to server.

There are also element tree. Which tree should be used?

How to get child widgets of a widget? Could not find methods like:

```
 getParet()
 getChildren()
```

This is not for testing code.

How to get the widget by its key (string) to get the root of the subtree?

Comment: I code Flutter for almost 2 years & never see this method. I don't think there is any solution possible. Maybe you should use `TextEdittingController` and collect them all.

Comment: Is there a way to get children widgets of a widget? Wondering what API the widget inspector is using to build widget tree. thanks